# Shopify how to check if customer abondoned the cart

Tags: shopify

I am creating an app in which i need the customer who abondoned the cart. Means if a customer added product to cart and then go to checkout and left checkout without payment then i need to get that customer's details through app. Please let me know how to do that.

Tha ks

Answer (score 0):

Hope these links will help you in getting details of the customers abandoned the cart:

https://help.shopify.com/manual/orders/abandoned-checkouts

https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/abandoned_checkouts